# How to find $f(x)$ from $x - 1 = \sin(\pi x)$

Tags: functions

How to turn $x - 1 = \sin(\pi x)$ into $f(x)$?

Also, I find that the equation doesn't actually "equal". Let x = -1.25, the left hand side doesn't equal to the right hand side... why is that?

Comment: It's an equation to be solved. It's not true for all $x$, but there exists $x$  that satisfy it. What do you even mean by turning an equation into a function? Please explain.

Comment: That's because it holds only for certain $x$. Is $x^2-2x+1 = 0$? Yes for $x=1$.

Comment: Do you want to construct a fixed-point iteration like $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=1+\sin(\pi x_n)$? This maps $\Bbb R$ to $[0,2]$ to $[1,2]$ but is not necessarily contractive there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to solve for $x$. The best in this situation will be to graph the functions $x-1$ and $\sin (\pi x)$ and find the intersection points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are, supposedly, many ways to construct a function associated to such an equation. One is presented below.

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x-1=\sin{\pi x}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x-1\neq\sin{\pi x}$. In particular, the assertion "$\forall x,f(x)=1$" means that the equation $x-1=\sin{\pi x}$ is trivially satisfied by all $x$, and the assertion "$\forall x,f(x)=0$" means that this equation doesn't have any solution.

---

Thanks to Vizad, we can now state the following fact: $f$ is equal to one at one point of the real line, and for the rest $f$ is equal to zero.

Comment: I am sorry to say that your answer doesn't address at all the issue which is a misunderstanding of the OP : what he/she gives is an equation which has a single solution $x =1$ (see the graphical representation given by @Vizag). That's all. No hidden function there !

Comment: You're perfectly right :)